# android auto detect document edge in a image and crop

Tags: android

I want to make a an application like cam scanner or genius scan for

1. Automatic detect the document edge in the image
2. Ability to move the corners of the edges identified (like this: [move the corners of the edge](http://i60.tinypic.com/i2ot3b.jpg) )
3. Cropping the image after accepting / redefined manually edges

What are the steps to make a similar application? There are code examples (or step-by-step tutorials) from which to take inspiration?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but your question is a bit too "high level" to be answered appropriately here. Search for tutorials for edge detection in Android, try them out, then come back with specific questions if needed.

Comment: @Omar: Did you found the way to do this functionality. I am going to implement the same what you have asked. Please share the ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @Omar, Have you find any solution for the same, I wanted it thanx

Comment: did you find anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo) from Android.

With this library you can crop, adjustes edge in the imag, apply filters and more.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.